# where are good netbean tutorial for building UI desktop apps?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.8

I've googled but can't seem to find dedicated tutorial series to building desktop UI apps on netbean.

Can someone point to a good site ?

Comment: are you talking about developing GUIs using NetBeans or an application running on the NetBeans platform? P.S. my answer is about developing GUIs using NetBeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there are very many tutorials out there on this subject; the NetBeans IDE's GUI editor makes laying out Java Swing GUI components fairly simply -- about ten minutes of experimentation and you should be able to lay out a GUI. As for handling GUI events, triggering changes in the GUI as a result, etc., that requires knowledge of Java Swing for which there are plenty of [Java Swing tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=Java+Swing+tutorial) out there.

Comment: Open the sample apps. Play. Learn. Read.